# Why fibres are strong only in one direction?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, polymers

Why fibres are strong only in the direction they are oriented?Why they break if we pull at right angle to their orientation?

[image]

Here each blue line represents combination of polymeric chains.

Comment: Could you clarify if you refer to an individual molecule, or a composite of them? I suspect that the answer might change.

Comment: Each blue line represents combination of polymeric chain.

Answer (score 2):

Fibres are made of long linear molecules, in which the atoms are bound by covalences C-C or C-O. Usually it is a long C-C-C-C-C-C-O-C-C-C, with one O from time to time. Such bonds are hard to break. But paralleled fibres are hold together by van der Wals forces, which are rather weak. They are not difficult to  get separated. That is why a fiber can be easily split in two in the sense of the length, and only in this sense.